# Amazon RDS Database connections strange behaviour

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We're experiencing some problems with the database connections at Amazon RDS. If you have a look at the graph below, the connections grow up and then suddenly fall down, like a sawtooth wave.

[image: DB Connections last 24 h]

The database instance is a t2.small, but we changed it after the 150 peak to a t2.large, but sawtooth wave is still there, although not so wide.

There are several databases, mainly InnoDB, some MyIsam.
Total size of tables is 0.87 GB, general_log and slow_log are activated.

The main problem is that we have to start a process with a lot of queries, which consumes a lot of database resources (it should take about 30 minutes, but only uses one connection), and when we start it, we always reach the max_connections limit and all the apps consuming this database break.

I don't understand why it grows and then falls down, I would be grateful if someone could explain this.

Also, after reaching max_connections, the database is blocked until we increase the instance class. This takes about 10 minutes.

We'd like not to upgrade database to a more powerful one, as this would be quite expensive. Perhaps there is something adjustable?

Thank you

Comment: How many applications are connected to this database? If you configure a local MySQL server don't you see the same behavior? At first sight my guess is that its application related..

Comment: There are about 20 web applications, with a total of about 50 instances. At local MySQL it is difficult to test, because we'd have to simulate all the requests we have at production

Comment: You pointed me to the right direction jfneis: The problem was a nodeJS application, which didn't close the MySQL connection. With so many applications, it was difficult, but we had a closer look at general_log and found that this application didn't quit connections. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped! I posted it as an answer, could you mark it as correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like its an application related problem.

Check DB connection pool configurations of your applications.

If not successful, try to install a local database and check if the behavior remains.